# Jarring https://github.com/FlowingMedia/TimeFlow

Tags: java, analytics

Good morning!

In Eclipse I receive no errors when running/building the project

`Running TimeFlow 0.5 No existing settings file found.`

When the application is Jarred
The following Error happens

`Running TimeFlow 0.5 No existing settings file found. java.io.FileNotFoundException: intro.gif (The system cannot find the file specified) at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:216) at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157) at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:111) at timeflow.app.AboutWindow.<init>(AboutWindow.java:24) at timeflow.app.TimeflowAppLauncher.main(TimeflowAppLauncher.java:26) java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read the array length because "s" is null at timeflow.app.TimeflowApp.getVisibleFiles(TimeflowApp.java:603) at timeflow.app.TimeflowApp.init(TimeflowApp.java:95) at timeflow.app.TimeflowAppLauncher$1.run(TimeflowAppLauncher.java:33) at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:771) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716) at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399) at                     java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:741) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)`

I have moved Images from images/ to the root directory of the project, in the source and copied the folder with the pointer to images/ to where the jar is located and this error persists

I have modified the build path to include the images folder and the images are added to the jar but not in an images folder, just to the root directory of the jar

Any help is welcome
I wish you the very best and thank you for your time!

Comment: Unfortunately the code is not hugely packaging-friendly as it depends on resources but those are read as `File`s. It will run from a jar as long as directories 'settings' and 'images' are off the current directory

Comment: you are a GOAT;; I spent ages trying to make compilation and carrying those files into a complete jar and your solution, which i should've saw but didnt is excellent man;; just incredible, thank you